# Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have two buttons with `onclick` event handlers that process information from two `grid views` on the page. One button for each gv. These are situated on top of each other nested in a `html` table structure.

The buttons are used to export the `grid` date into an `Excel` document (see code below)

The top button and `grid` when `click` on the button works fine but the bottom button throws a `ThreadAbortException: Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.`

Naturally I've Google-d for this but some of the top results were dealing with `Response.Redirect()` calls rather than `Response.End()`. One such post at [Forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/984756.aspx) has the same error on the same method call but the solution was to changing the code `Response.Redirect()` with an error page as parameter - again not related to what I have.

Another [search at Microsoft Suport page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/en-us) suggest a solution where `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` replaces `Response.End()`. I've tried this, the error goes away and so is the Excel download popup.

So I don't know where to go from here. What's weird is that the same code (less `gridview` id) works for one but the other. Here is the code for your review and I've marked where the error is thrown. 
I thought perhaps I could spawn an new thread - would that alleviate the issue? I've never done a `multi-threaded` app but I'm up for a challenge.

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td align="left">
     <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" OnClick="btnExport_Click"
          Text="Export" Visible="false" />
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>                    
     <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnl1" Visible="false">
      <asp:GridView ID="gvCountTotalsCat" runat="server" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="false"
          CellPadding="3" PageSize="25" BackColor="White" BorderColor="MidnightBlue"
          BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="1px" CssClass="TextCompact" 
          GridLines="Vertical"
          OnRowDataBound="gridView_OnRowDataBound"
          EmptyDataText="Your request has returned zero records">
          <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
             <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeader" Text="Cat" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Literal ID="litWuc" runat="server" />
           </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Cat Entries" HeaderText="Cat Entries" />
           <asp:TemplateField>
           <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeader" />
           </HeaderTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Literal ID="litSum" runat="server" />
           </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
         </Columns>                                              
        </asp:GridView>
       </asp:Panel>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="left">
    <asp:Button ID="btnExport1" runat="server" OnClick="btnExport_Click1" 
         Text="Export" Visible="false" />
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>                         
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnl2" Visible="false">
     <asp:GridView ID="gvCountTotalsCat1" runat="server" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="false"
          AllowPaging="false" CellPadding="3" PageSize="25" BackColor="White"
          BorderColor="MidnightBlue" BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="1px" 
          CssClass="TextCompact" GridLines="Vertical" 
          OnRowDataBound="gridView_OnRowDataBound"
          EmptyDataText="Your request has returned zero records">
          <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
             <HeaderTemplate>
              <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderWuc" Text="Wuc" />
             </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Literal ID="litWuc" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Wuc Entries" HeaderText="Wuc Entries" />
           <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
              <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeader" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Literal ID="litSum" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>     
         </asp:GridView>
        </asp:Panel>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>



public void btnExport_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string attachment = string.Empty;
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    // Create a form to contain the grid
    HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
    frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";

    attachment = "attachment; filename=gvCountTotalsCat_" + _selectedSite + ".xls";
    gvCountTotalsCat.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);
    frm.Controls.Add(gvCountTotalsCat);

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

    frm.RenderControl(htw);

    Response.Write(sw.ToString());

    Response.End();
}



public void btnExport_Click1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string attachment = string.Empty;
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();

    // Create a form to contain the grid
    HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
    frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";

    attachment = "attachment; filename=gvCountTotalsCat1_" + _selectedSite + ".xls";
    gvCountTotalsCat1.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);
    frm.Controls.Add(gvCountTotalsCat1);

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

    frm.RenderControl(htw);

    Response.Write(sw.ToString());

    try
    {
 >> Error thrown here >>     Response.End();

    }
    catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException lException)
    {
        lException;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the scenario where the second button fails, do you click the second button as soon as the page loads, or only after clicking the first button?

Comment: Also, why do you need to create a form to hold the grid?  Just curious.

Comment: The second button fails even if I click it before the first. The page can "sit" there for a while - no matter how long. I'm not sure if I understand your second question about needing a form. the code was given to me to take over, it works in other pages except here.

Comment: Differential diagnosis time.  If you were to change the code for the second export button so that it rendered the first grid rather than the second, does it cause the same error?  (Since there's no obvious difference in the code, I'm wondering if the difference is in what's being rendered. At least this will let us rule that out.)

Comment: Also, I note that both grids call `gridView_OnRowDataBound`.  Is that deliberate?  Just checking.

Comment: That was great idea but it did not work. I swapped the code between the two buttons so that the top button exports the data from bottm grid and vice versa. So top button export worked but no the bottom button.

Comment: In the `gridView_OnRowDataBound` I'm intercepting the original `DataTable` creating a clone and making formatting adjustments to rows, including inserting a blank row as separator between similar groups of data rows. But the end of that I'm putting things back to the `DataTable` and binding it to the gridview.

Comment: I assume your wrapping the `Response.End()` in a try/catch was something you started doing after the problem showed up?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26246/discussion-between-risho-and-ann-l)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It runed out that I have both grids and buttons in one `Update Panel` and only the top button was set as a `PostBackTrigger`. After I added the second one `<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExport1" />` and that solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

There is a handy way to deal with "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack." issues. You need to write on the Output window.

Add using System.Diagnostics;

Add a Try/Catch for the line that is erroring

In the Catch add these lines

```
try
{ ..}
 catch(Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.ToString());
}
```

Just debug and check the Output window

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved using an `ASPxGridViewExporter` without getting a `ThreadAbortException`.

Try the following code snippet:

```
try
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Write the content of the xlsx to the stream
        gridViewExporter.WriteXlsx(stream, new XlsxExportOptions(TextExportMode.Text, false, false));

        if (Response == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Write the byte content to the output
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", StringMngr.SafeFormat("attachment; filename=\"{0}.xlsx\"", "xlsxFileName"));
        Response.ContentType = "Text/xlsx";
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;

        if (stream.Length > 0)
        {
            Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
        }

        Response.Flush();
        Response.SuppressContent = true;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.Error("An error occured while downloading in xlsx format.", ex);
}
```

It downloads the excel file without getting a `ThreadAbortException` with the message of:

> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

and without getting the following error message when opening the excel file:

> Excel found unreadble content in myFilename.xlsx. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this book, click Yes.

Hope it helps! :)